# react private router redirect

Tags: reactjs, router

I have an api to check if user is logged in or not, and I want to redirect page by checking the response code from api, not sure how to write it?

api:

```
 case 'loggedin':
                $result = $_SESSION['sessionOBJ']->logged_in();
                if($result == true){
                    echo json_encode($result); //login
                    http_response_code(200); 
                }else{
                    http_response_code(401); //not login
                } 
            break;
```

privateRouter:

```
import React from "react";
import { Route, Redirect } from "react-router-dom";
// token
import { getToken } from "../../utils/session";


const PrivateRouter =({component: Component, ...rest}) => {
    return (
        <Route
          {...rest}
          render={routeProps => (
          getToken() ? <Component {...routeProps} /> : <Redirect to="/" />    // "/" is login page path
          //getToken() === 200 ? <Component {...routeProps} /> : <Redirect to="/" />   
          )}
        />
      );
}

export default PrivateRouter;
```

and the getToken : I want to redirect to private page when reponse code is 200, otherwise stay in the login page.

```
export function getToken(){
    return axios.get(
                `http://localhost:80/doctorbooking/api/api?action=loggedin`,
                {withCredentials: true},
    ) 
}
```

Comment: And what is happening when you run the above code?

Comment: can login and logout successfully, but when I type the private url directly, still can go that page after logout, does not redirect to the login page.

Comment: if I change the  getToken() to check the sessionStorage instead of get api, it can works fine. private page only showed after login. and after logged out, it will redirect to login page even type the private page url directly.

Comment: So the issue is your `axios.get`, probably not router. Make sure you debug that correctly. Are you sure `getToken()` is returning false when logged out?

Comment: I just know the response.status from getToken is 401 when logged out, not sure the result return from getToken()...and I tried to use .then(res=>{}) and .catch to return the response code and changed a little bit in the private code (just comment out in the question:: getToken === 200), but not worked...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at the documentation, it seems that `axios.get` returns a [Promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise). This means you'll only know if the user is authenticated when that Promise has been fulfilled. In that case, you'll need to update the component when this happens. Try something like this:

```
import React, {useState, useEffect} from "react";
import { Route, Redirect } from "react-router-dom";
import { getToken } from "../../utils/session";

const PrivateRouter = ({component: Component, ...rest}) => {

  const [ isAuthenticated, setIsAuthenticated ] = useState(null)

  useEffect(() => {

    getToken()
      .then(() => setIsAuthenticated(true))
      .catch(() => setIsAuthenticated(false))

  }, [])

  return (
    <Route
      {...rest}
      render={routeProps => (
        isAuthenticated === null
          ? null
          : isAuthenticated === false
            ? <Redirect to="/" />
            : <Component {...routeProps} />
      )}
    />
  );
}

export default PrivateRouter;
```

In the above, I'm updating the `isAuthenticated` state only when the Promise has been fulfilled. If the `isAuthenticated` is set to `null` (which it is initially), it means we're still waiting on the Promise result. In that case, we simply render `null` for React (which equates to nothing). You could, instead, render a loading component.

Comment: fyi I've added a `catch` to the promise in the event that `getToken` fails.

Comment: Great! Read up on [Promises](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) and how they work. They're a fundamental JS tool these days.

Comment: This is a good answer as its important you do not render the routes when the API call is still loading or you will get a React State Error.